# Apply an Excel formula in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this table:
[Table that i have turned into DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epvRP.png)
I want to apply this following Excel formula but in Pandas in a new column :
"=IF(P2="Organisation";O2;IF(R2="Organisation";Q2;IF(T2="Organisation";S2;IF(V2="Organisation";U2;IF(X2="Organisation";W2;IF(Z2="Organisation";Y2;IF(AB2="Organisation";AA2;INDEX(AI:AI;ROW()-1;1))))))))"

Can you help me, please ?
Best regards,

I have tried the ffill() pandas function but i didn't manage to manipulate it correctly,

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the logic you've described using Pandas, you can use the numpy.select function to apply multiple conditions and choose the corresponding values. Here's how you can implement the logic in a new column: # Assuming df is your DataFrame and the columns are named according to your Excel formula

```
# Adjust column names as needed

conditions = [
    (df['P'] == 'Organisation'), df['O'],
    (df['R'] == 'Organisation'), df['Q'],
    (df['T'] == 'Organisation'), df['S'],
    (df['V'] == 'Organisation'), df['U'],
    (df['X'] == 'Organisation'), df['W'],
    (df['Z'] == 'Organisation'), df['Y'],
    (df['AB'] == 'Organisation'), df['AA']
]

# The default value if none of the conditions are met
default_value = df['AI'].shift(1)

df['NewColumn'] = np.select(conditions, default_value, default=df['AI'])
```

This code assumes that your DataFrame is structured similarly to your Excel formula, with columns 'P', 'Q', 'R', ..., 'AB', 'AI'. Adjust the column names accordingly if they are different in your actual DataFrame.